# how to intersect multiple table in sql server? number of table should be decide on runtime depends on another query's result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, intersect

I want to know how to perform Intersect multiple time depends on the number of counts comes from another select query using SQL server.

select count(*) from xyz table

select a.Namespace from a
intersect
select b.Namespace from b
intersect
select c.Namespace from c

Here this intersects can go to multiple times depends on the count.

Answer (score 0):

...intersect ~ distinct + exists(with NULL comparison)...

```
--object_id~Namespace
declare @cnt int = 1 --all objects

loop:

select distinct object_id
from sys.all_objects as a --all objects...
where @cnt> = 1 
and (@cnt < 2 or (@cnt >= 2 and exists(select * from sys.objects as b where b.is_ms_shipped=0 and (b.object_id = a.object_id or (b.object_id is null and a.object_id is null))))) --..which are user objects
and (@cnt < 3 or (@cnt >= 3 and exists(select * from sys.tables as b where b.object_id = a.object_id or (b.object_id is null and a.object_id is null)))) -- ...only tables...
and (@cnt < 4 or (@cnt >= 4 and exists(select * from sys.sql_dependencies as b where b.object_id = a.object_id or (b.object_id is null and a.object_id is null)))) --..with dependencies
option(recompile);


if @cnt <> 4
begin
    select @cnt = 4 --all objects+user objects+tables+with dependencies
    goto loop
end
```